# What does it mean when a dot appears in a logic gate other than the NOT gate? (in logic diagrams)

Tags: logic, circuits

For example, this gate: [image]

looks like an OR gate, except there's a dot to the right. The dot is reminiscent of the fact that there's a dot in the NOT gate, so I wonder if it has something to do with that. There's no NOT after this gate in the diagram I'm looking at, so this doesn't to be implementing NOT OR or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `NOR` gate. You can implement a `NOR` gate using a combination of a `OR` and a `NOT` gate. However, in MOSFET implementation or other technologies (i.e. electrical hardware architecture), we can build a `NOR` gate directly and more efficiently (i.e. more efficient than using a `OR` and a `NOT` gate). That's why we use `NOR` as well.

Comment: I see! So does the dot always mean "not" of whatever operation it's to the right of?